# Do not [append]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, clean-up

Following is a few uses of [append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/append), which are not so related:

- appending to files (replacement [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io))
- some jQuery append* methods ([1600+ Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/append+jquery))
- Python list `append` method ([200+ Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/append+python+list))

The tag also has over 3600 Questions but only 7 Followers... it does not look very useful. It needs cleaning, and should disappear at the end.

Comment: How many clean-up requests do you have active now, Tshepang?

Comment: [9 requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A321731+[clean-up])

Comment: And do not [insert] (7534 question), [delete] (6480 question).  Etcetera, can keep going for a while.  These are **contextual** tags of course.  They are useful.  Do **not** delete them, that re-activates far too many questions for no good reason.

Comment: @HansPassant How is [append] [insert] [delete] useful? Are there experts on these tags out there?

Comment: @mason experts/followers are a red hering, even though they are a strong indication one might have overlooked something (there are 7 for append). contextual tags like append, insert, delete or bluefeets beloved pivot describe the question, though they have a stronger dependence on additional tags than language-tags have. If I said a question was about strings, you'd be swimming. If I added the language and append, then you'd begin to have an idea. Anyway, this request does not answer the points [Shog9's guidance on tag-burnination raises](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190).

Comment: ... Especially, how does it hurt? Which more useful and specific tags are displaced? Is it really meaningless where it is used?

Comment: The nice thing about bad tags is that if you add these to your ignore tags, you filter out silly questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator can you write an Answer that shows how this Question fails Shog9 checks.

Comment: You can add the StringBuilder#append(String s); method from Java to your list as well.

Comment: @Rudi there's that and some PHP method/function as well.